# Construct an XPath query which filters nodes based on the quantity of its children?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<person-group person-group-type="author">
    <name>
        <surname>Chen</surname>
        <given-names>J-Y</given-names>
    </name>
</person-group>
<person-group person-group-type="author">
    <name>
        <surname>Cisse</surname>
        <given-names>F</given-names>
    </name>
</person-group>
<person-group person-group-type="author">
    <name>
        <surname>Dahou</surname>
        <given-names>T</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Foucher</surname>
        <given-names>V</given-names>
    </name>
</person-group>
```

I am trying to design an XPath query which will only return  elements *only if* they have more than one  element.

I've tried everything within my knowledge, and also combed through XPath and XQuery documentation for the past few hours. Nothing I've read tells me if I can filter nodes based on the *quantity* of their children.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following XPath expression:

```
//person-group[count(name) > 1]
```

It selects all `person-group` elements which have more than one `name` child.

---

If you want to query the amount of *all element children*, you can generalize the above query to

```
//person-group[count(*) > 1]
```

Comment: Perhaps less obviously, you can also do `//person-group[name[2]]` which selects all `person-group` elements that have a second child.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Do you know of any documentation where I can learn about some of XPath's more advanced operators?

Comment: The current version of XPath is 3.1. You can find a good [tutorial here at Altova](https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3). BTW The answer only consists of XPath-1.0 features.